# How to read BLE characteristic values using BTFramework?

Tags: .net, windows, bluetooth

I am able to read characteristic values from a Bluetooth LE device using nRF Connect for Mobile without any issues.

I am attempting to read characteristic values from the same Bluetooth LE device using the demo version of BTFramework (.NET Bluetooth).

`Int32 Res = Client.ReadCharacteristicValue(Characteristic, OpFlag(), out Value, Protection());`

I have two questions:

1. How do I associate a wclBluetoothErrors error number with an error name? So far, I have been clicking each error name in the online documentation to observe the error number until I find one that matches the response. This is sloooow. (update: I found the answer; at btframework.com navigate to DOCUMENTATION->BLUETOOTH FRAMEWORK->ERROR CODES.)
2. When I attempt to read one of the characteristics (that is readable and writeable) without encryption or authentication, the response (`Res`) is 0x000510D, which is "The attribute requires encryption before it can be read or written.", so I enabled encryption and now I get the response 0x0005101F, which is "The target server did not provide an appropriate network response." Also, the value of `Value` is null. I have tried turning on Forced Indicators and subscribing without any effect. I have tried this for a characteristic whose value is an array of more than one byte and for a characteristic whose value is an array of one byte. What else can I try to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Full List of Bluetooth Framework error codes with its description can be found by this link: https://www.btframework.com/errors.htm
Simple search by an error's HEX value helps to find its description.

Also you can easy add error-to-text convertion into your application (Bluetooth Framework provies such method): https://github.com/btframework/ErrorToText
You can use on-line and off-line errors.xml file in that case.

Before use encryption on a GATT characteristic you must pair with your device.

More details about GATT usage can be found by this link: https://www.btframework.com/gatt.htm

Also there are some demos on GitHub: https://github.com/btframework

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to find an applicable demo on GitHub. I did not see which one would help me, so I am continuing to use the .NET Framework demo solution bundled with the BTFramework download, specifically the GattClient project. I discovered, selected the target device, selected Encryption, clicked Pair, clicked Connect, clicked Get Services, clicked Get Characteristics, and then clicked Get value. The response is 0x0005101F. Should I be performing these steps in a different order?

Comment: Some devices require write special key to a specific characteristic before it allows to read from others. Its hard to say what is your device requirement so would be great to know more about your device and its attributes (services and characteristics).

Comment: I was hoping that the success that I had with the Android app (nRF Connect for Mobile) would somehow map over to a desktop tool that I can use on a Windows 7 computer. We are adding BLE capability to an existing test system and need implementation complete earlier than we could bring in a replacement Windows 11 computer.

Comment: Well, as I wrote its hard to say what your device needs. Also, Windows 7 does not support BLE. So you need to use BLED112 dongle or BlueSoleil drivers on Windows 7. Also, which characteristic you are trying to read? If it is one of the system then Windows limits access to it. If your device is HID or similar Windows does not allow to work with that device as well. So, as I wrote, more details about your device helps to recomend how to use it on Windows platform.

Comment: @HamiltonWoods  So I tested it on Windows 11 with some test device I have here. On Windows 10 it gives a little bit different errors on Windows 11: If device has protected (secure) characteristics it returns 0x0005100D error (WCL_E_BLUETOOTH_LE_INSUFFICIENT_ENCRYPTION). After pairing if you write the characteristic with wrong protection (None, Authentication, Authentication and Encryption) it returns 0x0005101F (WCL_E_BLUETOOTH_LE_COMMUNICATION_FAILED) error. And only if you write it with correct protection (Encryption) the operation is success. Reading allowed on my device without that.

Comment: @HamiltonWoods nRF Connect also requires pairing with such devices.